# How to synchronize JOOQ with SpringBatch JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-batch, jooq, transactionmanager

I'm working with Spring batch and trying to build TASKLET with two 'ORM' frameworks:
use jdbcTemplate for simple queries, and JOOQ framework for more complex query.

Here is a part of spring config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDbcp_MySQL" /> 
</bean>
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<job id="importProductsJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="readWrite">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk  reader="multiResourceReader" 
                    processor="itemProcessor" 
                    writer="itemWriter" 
                    commit-interval="250" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
<bean id="itemWriter" class="com.myexample.writer.JdbcSequenceWriter">
    <property name="dataSourceTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <!-- and some more specific properties -->
</bean>
```

I initialise my ORMs at setter in com.myexample.writer.JdbcSequenceWriter:

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2; 
private DSLContext dslContext;

public void setDataSourceTransactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManager trxManager) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(trxManager.getDataSource());
    this.jdbcTemplate2 = new JdbcTemplate(trxManager.getDataSource());
    dslContext = DSL.using(trxManager.getDataSource(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
}
```

Both jdbcTemplate's has one session and I can INSERT a record using 'jdbcTemplate', and find this record using SELECT with 'jdbcTemplate2'. But if try to INSERT a record with any 'jdbcTemplate' and find it using dslContext (JOOQ ORM) I have empty result.
I undarstand that Spring Batch use some tricky tansaction manager, witch rollback all the operation if 'writer' can't finish all it's operations. But how can I synchronize another framework with single transaction manager?

Comment: Just checking: How did you configure that data source? The jOOQ [manual suggest you use Spring's `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring/)

Answer (score 2):

The *generally expected* behavior is what you observe between `JdbcTemplate` and `dslContext`: each acquires a separate DB connection from the `DataSource`.

Your first finding, with two `JdbcTemplate` instances, is *special* behavior which `JdbcTemplate` had to be specifically designed for. Apparently, all its instances share the same connection internally.

You can make both work (probably) by first acquiring a JDBC `Connection` from the `DataSource` and then passing it to both the `JdbcTemplate` and `dslContext`. This is not the supported usage pattern and there may still be problems with it.

Once you have acquired a connection, naturally you will be in charge of releasing it as well.